# Using CSS animation causes other random links on page to jump when hovered in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform, css-animations

I have a simple GIF image that I am applying a keyframe animation to (to make it spin infinitely), and for some reason, if I hover over links elsewhere on the page, they randomly jump up or down by a pixel or two.

When I remove the DOM element that has the animation on it (the image) the jumping does not occur, leading me to believe it is somehow caused by the CSS animation somehow. This ONLY happens in Chrome, even the most recent update of Chrome.

I have read all other related questions on here and nothing has resolved it yet, it is NOT the `-webkit-backface-visibility` fix needed here.

Example CSS:

```
@mixin spin {
    -webkit-animation: spin360 1.26s infinite linear;
    animation: spin360 1.26s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin360 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin360 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.animated-image {
    position: absolute;
    @include spin;
}
```

Example DOM:

```
<h3 class="header">
    <a href="#" class="link">Heading title</a>          
</h3>

<div class="animated-image"><img src="../img/loader.gif"></div>
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/caseytrombley/pen/YWYqRQ

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you are experiencing. That means using a service like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or the like to show the issue (make sure the issue is present in your example).

Comment: You should probably have position *values* on the image div.

Comment: Here's my working example: http://codepen.io/caseytrombley/pen/YWYqRQ

Comment: I should mention that the issue doesn't occur in my working example, only in my application, however that is way too much code to put into Codepen. The heading (h3) is jumping up or down by 1px when I hover it. It happens only once after a refresh, and only in Chrome

Comment: When the CSS animated DIVs are removed or commented out the jumping does not happen anymore which leads me to think that CSS animations do something to the DOM in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in chrome the img it isn't vertical and horizontal centered.

I suggest you use flexbox to centered and must be fixed

Other way is use the img like background image and put

```
background-position: center center;
background-size: contain;
```

but I can imagine it's an animated gif, in that case must be fixed with flex